# LINQ Query problem. Need to check if exists

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 fields: `urlName`, `displayName` and `active`. This is check for edit record. What I want to do here is to check `UrlName` is unique in Db, but at the same time, if user has already saved the Url but changed `DisplayName` and `Active` then the record should update.

Any one tell me how to solve that.

```
public bool NothingExceptUrlNameExists(string urlName, string displayName, bool active)
        {
            return (from p in _db.SubMenus
                    where p.UrlName == urlName && (p.DisplayName != displayName || p.DisplayName == displayName) && (p.Active != active || p.Active == active)
                    select p).Any();
        }
```

updating record like

```
 TryUpdateModel(existingMenu);
                _menu.Add();
```

**This is what I want to achieve**

My other 2 values should be added in Query DisplayName and Active. Suppose "Contact" UrlName already in DB. I am loading values from dropdown returning UrlName="About", DisplayName="About Us", Active = true. Now editing record. Here are the condition to match.

1 - UrlName="About", DisplayName="About Test", Active = true --> This should update.

2 - UrlName="About", DisplayName="About Us", Active = false --> This should update.

3 - UrlName="About", DisplayName="About Test", Active = false --> This should update.

Important : 4 - UrlName="newnotexist", DisplayName="About test", Active = false --> **This should update UrlName and rest if changed.**

5 - UrlName="Contact", DisplayName="About Test", Active = false --> **This should not update and generate error.**

I hope you understand what I want to do.

Comment: `(p.DisplayName != displayName || p.DisplayName == displayName)` and `(p.Active != active || p.Active == active)` will always be true. Also it's not very clear as to what you are trying to achieve. Can you rephrase/elaborate ?

Comment: @Bala R , Thanks for the reply. This is for Edit form. UrlName is unique in DB but DisplayName and Active are not. I have form with these 3 fields. You load 3 fields from selecting dropdown. Now he wants to edit DisplayName and Active with same UrlName than it should update. In another scenario he wants to change urlname different than what is load (might change other values) but not unique and try to save it which should give error. I hpe its clear now?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Based on the updated question, and if I understand it correctly, I think this solution will work for you.

```
var urlNameExists = _sb.Any(x => x.UrlName == urlName && x.Id != currentEditId);

if (urlNameExists)
     throw Exception("A record with that UrlName already exists");

TryUpdateModel(existingMenu);
_menu.Add();
```

Comment: Thats the simplest and perfect answer. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool alreadyInDb = (from p in _db.SubMenus where p.UrlName = urlName select p).Count() > 0;

if (alreadyInDb)
{
    bool shouldAddRecord = (from p in _db.SubMenus where p.DisplayName == displayName && p.Active == active select p).Count() == 0;

    if (shouldAddRecord)
    {
        TryUpdateModel(existingMenu);
        _menu.Add();
    }
}
```

Comment: bool alreadyInDb = (from p in _db.SubMenus where p.UrlName = urlName select p).Any();

Answer (score 3):

```
private void Update(string urlName, string display, bool active)
{
    item = db_.SubMenus.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UrlName == urlName);

    if (item == null)
    {
        // Save new item here
    }
    else
    {
        if (item.DisplayName == display && item.Active == active)
        {
            // Error, fields haven't changed and url already in db
        }
        else
        {
            // Save because fields have changed
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @aligray - If UrlName is unique in the DB (via Unique Index Constraint) then your else (aka else `if (count > 1)`) will never occur. You can change your query to be `.Any()` which will return true or false based if the record exists or not. Rather than returning a count. Then you can just write `if (exists) {} else {}`

Comment: @aligray , Sorry your approach is not right. I posted that This is for Edit form. UrlName is unique in DB but DisplayName and Active are not. I have form with these 3 fields. You load 3 fields from selecting dropdown. Now he wants to edit DisplayName and Active with same UrlName than it should update. In another scenario he wants to change urlname different than what is load (might change other values) but not unique and try to save it which should give error.

Comment: @pirzada - So if editing a menu, you want to check that UrlName is not already used by another record that is not the current edited one? Then you can make your where include `p.Id != currentId`, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Phill , @aligray , @bdparrish I have updated my question. See bottom of it for more explanation.

Comment: @Phill hmm p.Id != currentId. I am looking into it. let me check.

Comment: @pirzada - I hope aligray doesn't mind, i edited his answer to cater for your question update. That should cover your scenarios, note the `if (exists)` is now `if (!exists)`

Comment: @Phill No Problem! But I was half way through editing myself :)

Comment: @aligray - haha ok, I added my answer.